# How to add a field dynamically to a CustomUser model inheriting from mongoengine.django.auth.User?

Tags: django, pymongo, mongoengine

I am using mongoengine with django. I have a CustomUser model inheriting from mongoengine.django.auth.User that defines some fields. I have a field, which is only needed for some users. I don't want this field in every User objects. As mongoengine.django.auth.User is inherited from mongoengine.Document from which CustomUser model is inherited I can't add fields into it dynamically.So I made my CustomUser model to inherit from both mongoengine.django.auth.User and mongoengine.DynamicDocument

```
from mongoengine.django.auth import User
from mongoengine import DynamicDocument

class CustomUser(User, DynamicDocument):
    # fields
```

Using this method I am able to dynamically create fields for CustomUser. But I want to know if it is ok to do this. If there are any other better methods available, please suggest.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes thats totally valid as the `mongoengine.django.auth.User` class is inheritable.

Alternative approaches might be to extend explicitly for different types of user eg:

```
class AdminUser(User):
    role = StringField()
```

Then you can just use:

```
User.objects(username=blah)
```

And if that `User` is an `AdminUser` it will return the correct class instance